# New laptop extremely hot

Tags: laptop, overheating

I just bought a laptop (ASUS N550 with Intel 4700MQ processor) and I'm noticing that it gets REALLY hot very easily. I've been copying files into it for like 30 min and the whole laptop is pretty hot, and some areas (like the area between the keyboard and the screen) are EXTREMELY hot (if I put my fingers there for a few seconds it hurts).

I've downloaded SpeedFan to test the internal temperatures, getting the following results:

1. While copying large amounts of files, the 4 cores get to temperatures just above 80C. The **Temp1** sensor (I'm not sure what it measures) showed 94C.
2. After leaving the laptop idle for some time, the cores indicate usually temperatures between 60C-70C. The **Temp1** sensor indicates around 80C.

The fans seem to be working (at least I hear them), but I can't feel any air coming out from anywhere in the laptop.

Are those temperatures normal? Or do they indicate that there's something wrong with it?

Comment: Before giving any answer to your question, I advise you to check for the technical specifications of your processor. There you will surely find the MAX normal degree.

Comment: For comparison, my laptop gets up to 84c with my nvidia 320. Intel recommends that the cpu not get over 100c. http://ark.intel.com/products/29762/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7700-%284M-Cache-2_40-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29

Comment: @Diego the MAX temperature is 100C, but I would assume that it would take a lot more work to get it to that level... The "normal" temperature should be around 50C for what I've researched, so getting to 60C-70C just for being idle worries me

Comment: Well, as long as you just bought it, you can always contact ASUS support line and ask for advise ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that the "problem" was that I had the power setting in High Performance, changing it to Balanced keeps the temperature normal.

I still think, though, that it gets way too hot in HP mode, I get that I runs to full capacity but the whole laptop is like a freaking oven just after a few minutes of use, so maybe I have some problem with the cooling system, I'll see if it's something that needs to be checked out.

Comment: A laptop cooler ( basically a piece of plastic with fans ) should help a little.  It appears the laptop you purchase shouldn't be placed in your lap.

Comment: Some laptops (older HPs were known for this) get quite hot in certain spots (eg, the palm rests) under "normal" conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I actually spent some time trying to fix this over the weekend. I think the power4gear hybrid that is shipped wit the computer does not work correctly after putting the computer to sleep. I uninstalled this and now the fan kicks in much earlier. It wasn't kicking in for me at times.